# How to pull out the most deeply nested child from an element in dom using Javascript?

Tags: nested, nodes

// Define a function deepestChild() that pulls out the most deeply nested child from div#grand-node. (Remember, you can iterate over elements and call querySelector() and querySelectorAll() on them. //

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript Hide and Seek</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="app">
      <ul class="unranked-list">
        <li>2</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="ranked-list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="ranked-list">
        <li>12</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>10</li>
      </ul>

      <div id="nested">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div class="target">
                1
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="grand-node">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                boo!
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Oh! thanks for mentioning that, i am basically new to this site, but it has been fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
//pass in a jquery object
function deepestChild(node) {
  node.find(':last');
}

var node = $('#grand-node');
var mostDeep = deepest(node);
```

Without jQuery:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#grand-node div');
var mostDeep = nodes[nodes.length- 1];
```

if you need to make a function out of it, here is one that offers flexibility if you are searching for other deepest children. The id parameter is the id of the element where you want to start searching, and the element parameter is the type of element you are looking for:

```
function deepestChild(id, element) {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} ${element}`);
  if(!nodes.length) return false;
  return nodes[nodes.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function deepestChild() {
  let element = document.getElementById('grand-node');

  while (element.firstElementChild) {

    element = (element).firstElementChild;
  }
  return element;
```

}

The main problem that I was having with this is that my condition was:
...while (element.firstChild)...
the problem with this is it will return true it is an element node, a text node, or a comment node and it's required to return true only if it is an element node and that is why you need this condition to be:
...while(element.firstElementChild)...
this might help too: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_firstchild.asp